# Why does react display two different heights for the same HTML? Does componentDidUpdate include CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Does react take into account CSS when  rendering height?  I have this code:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    let height = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).offsetHeight;
    console.log(height);
    sendResizePopupMessage();
}
```

Now the first time I click the button, I get height = 250. The next time I get height 277. In both scenarios ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).innerHTML was the exact same, what would cause it to display different heights?

Here is my component:

```
<div className="popup-container container-fluid">
    <PopupHeader
        status={offerStatus}
        disabled={disabled}
        onCloseClick={() => this.handleCloseClick()}
        onToggleClick={() => this.handleToggleClick()}
    />
    {offers.length > 0 && this.state.shouldShowOffers && (
        <PopupTable offers={offers}
                    onClick={() => this.handleFindCheaperClick()}
                    disableFindCheaper={this.state.disableFindCheaper}
                    findCheaperMessage={this.state.findCheaperMessage}
        />
    )}
</div>
```

Comment: It may be because of the content inside of your popup. If there is anything loading on your first click like a font or image, that would potentially give you a different value for offset height the first time. But this is just a guess without seeing the component and content itself.

Comment: Added the component. And like I mentioned, I debugged the ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).innerHTML and the HTML itself is exactly the same in both scenarios

Comment: Which height value is correct? Where do the extra 27 pixels come from?

Comment: The 277 is correct. But I have no idea why there are two separate numbers if the HTML and styles stay exactly the same

Comment: That is your JSX. Could you share the entire component, including class methods and lifecycle methods? Something is updating in the component which is causing your componentDidUpdate() lifecycle method to fire. It's possible that there is an initial state where you do not have any offers yet when the popup opens. That is my guess based on your conditional JSX.